# Android SwitchCompat thumb not aligned

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, switchcompat

I'm trying to use `SwitchCompat` in Android Studio, I put this in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
```

but the thumb is not centered with the slider.

[image: Screenshot]

and this is my xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/allarme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: try to remove the margin bottom for a quick test.

Comment: Try to set `minHeight` and `maxHeight`

Comment: @Skizo no luck neither...

Comment: Please try to encapsulate it in a frame layout. then remove all attributes except id,width and height. Assign layout_gravity to the frame layout (as well as desired margins).

Comment: @Xyaren same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem: there is a bug in appcompat (v21.0.3 at the moment) that afflict hdpi devices.
More there: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78262

workaround:
copy this file in res/drawable-hdpi of your app: https://www.mediafire.com/?6c7537yi73m1e6m